# Visual Studio 2015 OpenCV Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow windows.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++

I've been learning a bit of c++ lately and i keep getting the same error for some reason.

Apparently, imshow isn't able to find the file.

My codes are

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img;
    img = imread("1.png");
    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout << "can't find da file\n\n" ;

    }
    cv::namedWindow("test");
    cv::imshow("test",img);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

- I've tried putting it in the project folder along with the ".exe",
- I tried listing the whole directory of the image using "/" and "\"
- I've also tried not using any extensions in the code but to no avail.

[Error Signs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQpIP.png)

Thanks for helping you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always advise the same thing for these cases. It just needs a little lateral thinking. Change your code to this

```
int main()
{
    ofstream test("test.txt");
    test << "I'm here!!\n";
}
```

Now run this program, it will *create* a file called `test.txt`. Find out where that file is on your system and that's where you should put your `1.png` file. Then you can go back to your original program confident that the file is in the right place and any remaining issues are a different problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot XD, it finally worked and apparently my image file was corrupted XD.